# how to search through a WebRequest

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

How would someone search through the response of a webrequest for a certain set of characters. For example I am making a program that gets the closings for my school district and I need the WebRequest to look for the word "... is closed today" and it will output the entire line of that text. Here is what I got so far. It returns the page in html (I believe):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        get_closings();
    }

    private void get_closings()
    {

         // Create a request for the URL. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
          "http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        text.Text = responseFromServer;
        // Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close ();
        response.Close();

    }

    private void text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Which returns with a bunch of stuff like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false">
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true">
<!--p_theUserAgent - ${p_theUserAgent}-->
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="168641655540" />
<meta property="og:url"              content="http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NBC4 Washington" />
<meta property="og:title" content="School Closings, Cancellations, and Delays "     />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media.nbcwashington.com/images/school-closings-graphic.gif" />
```

Also the part im looking for:

```
<h1>School Closings</h1>   

             <div id="schoolForecast">


                                           <h3 style="font-family:'Arimo',Arial,sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">Forecast: School's Open.</h3>
      <p class="schoolOpen">But don't worry, we update this page regularly so you'll be the first to know if your school is closing or will have delays due to bad weather. In the meantime, check your <a href='/weather/'>local weather</a> to see if things will change.</p>
                <p class="schoolOpen"></p>
                          </div>

       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use HTMLAgilityPack.  Google for it.

Example:

```
String HTML = @" <h1>School Closings</h1>  <div id=""schoolForecast""> <h3 style=""font-family:'Arimo',Arial,sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;"">Forecast: School's Open.</h3>  
                    <p class=""schoolOpen"">But don't worry, we update this page regularly so you'll be the first to know if your school is closing or will have delays due to bad weather. In the meantime, check your <a href='/weather/'>local weather</a> to see if things will change.</p>
    <p class=""schoolOpen""></p>  </div> </div> </div>";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
Doc.LoadHtml(HTML);

HtmlNode Node = Doc.GetElementbyId("schoolForecast");

MessageBox.Show(Node.InnerText);
```